How can Environment Variables be set in Android persistently?
What are the possible ways in which an end user or a developer can set the environment variables?
As per the research done till now,
There is no way for an Android user to set the environment variable through any Settings/Application.
Setting the Environment Variable using setenv does not set the environment variables persistently, and only does it till the application is running.
There are some environment variables across android and some specific to the app that are available, but there isn't any way to add any persisted environment variables without rooting.

You seem to already have figured it out for yourself, it's not possible without root. Also, it isn't really needed, because you can always set the variable at startup of your app. So what is it that you are asking, what do you want to know?

I just wanted confirmation that there aren't any other ways for the user to do this which I don't know of.
